# Sending value from a form to a html tag counter

Tags: php, html, forms, count, send

I am looking for a bit of code to do the following:

A form containing a single text field and a submit button, must send the value of the text field to a landing page that automatically counts how many html tags that this page contains.

E.g. if the text field states stackoverflow.com, the landing page should say (H1 tags = 20) with many more parameters to come.

How is this done? I know how to make a form, but I do not know how to make it send its value to the landing page.

```
<form action="landingpage.php/" method="post">
      The URL
<input type="text" name="cf_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is a perfect answer to your question.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
  Type In Something: <input name="random-info" type="text" size="25">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> <br> 

<?php
  echo "You Typed: " . $_GET['random-info'];
?>
```

you get the method into the url, then you can use them on another page.

Comment: Well, I couldn't get it to work. How does the form know where to send the random-info?

Comment: you dont do method"post" but you do method"get" it doesnt post your value's, but it puts them at the top of the url so you can use em on another link.

Answer (score 0):

To access data from a form it depends on the method. Since your code shows a post message you simply access it in the php on the landing page by user $POST_['cf_name'].

To learn more you can check out:
http://w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp about the post method and http://w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp about the get method.

Also an invaluable source is  [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) itself.

As far as counting the tags, not really sure what you are trying to achieve. 
If you are counting the tags in the page you create, just make a variable and add to it each time you put that specific tag on the page. 
Then you can put those values in a hidden field of the form to be passed into your landing page.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will see it that suits my need. I need to see how many parameters a page contains for analysis.